Installing LAMP + Laravel + valet
i am trying to install a LAMP environment(linux apache mysql php) + Laravel framework + Valet linux .
I would like some help if possible while i am going through this installment.
Currently i saw this on the laravel doc website about installing Valet :

... you should make sure that no other programs such as Apache or Nginx are binding to your local machine's port 80.

So i was wandering what does that mean , usually after installing apache i should allow it the port 80 in the firewall by running :
sudo ufw allow in "Apache"

So i should i NOT do that?
I want to gather information first before i run into installation.
Thank you very much.

by default, the port is 80, so ensure that there are no other web servers running on your machine that are already using port 80, since it will prevent Valet from binding to it and serving your local development sites. if 80 is blocked on firewall then u must allow it to listen.

Ok i see now,
I think Valet uses Nginx by default, which leads me to this question :
If my development environment uses Valet and therefore Nginx for testing , and then i change to Apache in my production , would it not be a bad decision, would i not get any results different than what i had, i usually make my development environment similar to my production.
Is there a way to make Valet uses Apache?

yes, changes in stack is bad, and you shouldn't use different versions in each enviroments. The answer is no. ref

All right, i will have to sacrifice Valet then and work with Apache, Thank you very much.
